# why does equals not work the same when items are cast to object?

Tags: c#

when i cast int and float to object and compare them the equality is always false. Why?

```
        float f = 0.0f;
        int i = 0;
        Console.WriteLine(f.Equals(i)); // true
        Console.WriteLine(i.Equals(f)); // false
        Console.WriteLine(i == f); // true
        Console.WriteLine("----------------");
        object obf = f;
        object obi = i;
        Console.WriteLine(obf.Equals(obi)); // false
        Console.WriteLine(obi.Equals(obf)); // false
        Console.WriteLine(obi == obf); // false
        Console.WriteLine("----------------");
```

Update:
this is NOT the case for the same type

```
        int i1 = 1;
        int i2 = 1;
        object oi1 = i1;
        object oi2 = i2;
        Console.WriteLine(oi1.Equals(oi2)); // true
        Console.WriteLine(oi2.Equals(oi1)); // true
```

Answer (score 9, accepted):

A `float` is only equal to another `float`, and an `int` is only equal to another `int`. The only lines which are returning `true` are these ones:

```
Console.WriteLine(f.Equals(i));
Console.WriteLine(i == f);
```

In both of these cases, there's an implicit conversion of the value of `i` to `float`, so they're equivalent to:

```
Console.WriteLine(f.Equals((float) i));
Console.WriteLine((float) i == f);
```

These conversions are just normal conversions required for overload resolution of methods and operators.

None of the rest of the lines involve that implicit conversion, so they're comparing the two different types, which gives a result of `false` even when it *is* comparing by value (which is the case with all the `Equals` calls). That's why using `Equals` on the boxed `int` values *does* return `true`, because that's comparing two values of the same type, *by value*.

In this case:

```
Console.WriteLine(obi == obf);
```

it's not even trying to compare numeric values - it's comparing the *references* for the boxed objects. As there are two different references, the result is `false` - and would be even if both values were of type `int`.

Comment: does the implicit conversion get handled at compile time?

Comment: @CharlesLambert: Yes. Have a look at the IL and you'll see it being performed.

Answer (score 3):

Others have already explained why `==` does not work as expected on your objects.

Regarding your edit: `oi1.Equals(oi2)` works because `Equals` is a virtual function and, thus, [`Int32.Equals(object)`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/de3wwa8z.aspx) is called, whose return value is defined as follows:

> *true* if obj is an instance of Int32 and equals the value of this instance; otherwise, *false*.

This also explains why `obi.Equals(obf))` returns false: `obf` is not an instance of Int32.

Answer (score 2):

You're boxing the int and float to an object, which means they're compared as references. Since they're not references to the same object, they're not equal.

See http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/yz2be5wk.aspx

Answer (score 2):

To understand more about what happens when you box value types, Shivprasad describes this quite succinctly here:

[Boxing and Unboxing](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/dotnet/6importentStepsDotNet.aspx?msg=3462442#Boxing%20and%20Unboxing)

Since you are boxing the value types to objects, you are now performing reference equality. Since they now reside at different memory locations in your example, will return false.

Answer (score 1):

When you've declared two objects they references a different memory location:

```
object obf = f;         // this simplified as new float(f)
object obi = i;         // this simplified as new int(i)
```

but try out following, let one object to reference an other:

```
obf = obi;
Console.WriteLine(obf.Equals(obi));
```

MSDN, [Object.Equals Method](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bsc2ak47.aspx)

> The default implementation of Equals supports reference equality for
>   reference types, and bitwise equality for value types. Reference
>   equality means the object references that are compared refer to the
>   same object. Bitwise equality means the objects that are compared have
>   the same binary representation.

Answer (score 0):

When you cast a value type to object, it is actually getting put in the heap and == compares references at that point, which will be false. (Simplified)

Answer (score 0):

Because `Equals` compares the address of the object reference and the two numbers are stored in different locations. if you compare the two value types Equals behaves correctly as it has been overridden for float, int, string and other types.

Answer (score 0):

Because they are assigned to different memeory cells.
2 objects are = only when they are the same object.
In the float and int part you get a true when you test the 2 variables because the runtime checks their value.
that's all!